# Edges noticeable on a THREE.CylinderGeometry despite using THREE.SmoothShading

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create a smooth-shaded cylinder using [three.js](http://threejs.org/).  Setting the `shading` parameter of my material to `THREE.SmoothShading` improves the appearance significantly, but the outline of the faces are still noticeable:

[image: Cylinder with THREE.SmoothShading]

What is preventing these faces from being shaded smoothly?

Comment: You answered your own question within 59 seconds of posting the question. How is that possible?

Comment: @WestLangley See the second paragraph on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Aha! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bit of an optical illusion.  The lighting in my scene is provided by one `THREE.AmbientLight` and three `THREE.DirectionalLight`'s, which cast harsh shadows.  The way in which these shadows were interacting was tricking my eyes into thinking the faces were being imperfectly shaded.  Turning all but one `DirectionalLight` off revealed that the shading is being applied as expected:

[image: Cylinder with smooth shading and only one light]